# 'Zone Battle' mode is unclear

Tags: wipeout-hd-fury, wipeout-omega-collection

One of the event types in the *Wipeout HD / Wipeout Fury* mode is *Zone Battle*.  The instructions are complicated and it's not really clear what's going on in-game; I seem to do either really well or come dead last.

What's the goal of Zone Battle, what do these boosts, shields, and barrier mechanics do, and what's a general strategy to win?

Comment: I believe the goal is to be the first player to hit a target zone (speed class). As for specific mechanics/strategies, I haven't played enough to be able to say anything about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zone Battle in Wipeout is a tricky beast to get at first so here's a rundown on how the game mode works.

---

**What's the goal of Zone Battle?**

The main goal of Zone Battle much like Zone is to get to the Zone Target before any of your opponents do. It is important to know that in Zone Battle drivers are unable to be eliminated and when destroyed they will simply respawn at a lower Zone Level.

If no racer is able to obtain the zone target after a set period of time the game will lower the zone target until someone is able to reach that target.

---

**How do you play Zone Battle**

Zone Battle is very similar to the original Zone gamemode with some added changes. First off much like zone you want to go over as many boost pads as possible, doing so will help you build up your boost/ shield bar which is vital to winning Zone Battle events. Driving over two boost pads are the minimum requirement in order to use either boost or shield, however do note that driving over more pads will increase the effect of your boost or shield.

When you fill up your bar you are able to do one of two actions with that full boost. The first is boosting, boosting lets you advance farther into the next Zone, however in Zone Battle there is an added function to boosting. Whenever you boost in Zone Battle you will leave behind a zone barrier as well. These have two uses one of which I will mention later, but colliding into these barriers will drain your ship's energy so try to avoid these for the most part. An important thing to note is the game will tell you when you are able to hit the zone target by boosting, so if you are close to winning build up your bar and boost into victory.

The second function you can do with your bar is use a shield. Using the shield is vital to restoring your ship's energy since activating the shield allows you to regain energy from doing actions that would normally hurt you such as hitting cars and walls. This shield does have another extremely important use though, it lets you pass through the Zone Barriers left behind from boosts and you actually restore the energy you would have lost from these barriers. Do note though that when you go through a barrier with a shield, the barrier is not removed like it is by normal collisions. **Barriers can only be removed by colliding with them unshielded.**

---

Once a driver hits the Zone Target the race will be over and a victor will be crowned. Once you get used to the mechanics you should be able to dominate the virtual circuit in Zone Battle.

Good Luck and Stay Fast

Source: http://wipeout.wikia.com/wiki/Zone_Battle

Comment: You can boost without a full bar, right, the zone advancement effect is just much more limited?  What's the difference in using shield between a full and low bar?

Comment: You require at a minimum 2 pads before you can use either boost or shield. When you fill up the bar more your boost gets more powerful advancing you farther, and your shield will last longer with more bar.